# No colour output if program run with exec

Tags: c, linux, stdout

I have a C program that runs

```
execvp("grep", args);
```

Where args is an array `{"grep", "test"}` (test being the word I want grep to find).
The issue is that grep's output is not coloured. In a normal bash shell, grep highlights `test` in red, but in my program's output it just prints the line like
`this is a test` with no highlighting or colours of any sort.

I'm also using execvp to execute some other commands which also produce coloured output in a bash shell, and have no colours in my output.

Is there any way to fix this? Something I need to do to `stdout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the correct option to `grep` in order to get it to colorize. Most likely, your shell environment includes:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

but `execvp` knows nothing about aliases.

So create the args array: `{"grep", "--color=auto", "test", 0}` and use that in your `execvp("grep", args);` call.